# client-certificate authentication for SSH

Tags: ssh, ssl, wireguard, authorization

My servers are incessantly being brute-force attacked on my SSH port.

I am using non-standard SSH port, firewall blacklist for port-scanners, and I am also using custom fail2ban-like script to ban offending IP addresses on my SSH port. However these attacks are distributed, and even if I block offending IP, there seems to be unlimited never-ending supply of new attacking IPs.

Is there some authentication mechanism, where the SSH server would only react to authorized clients?

I think something similar exists in wireguard. The server will completely ignore any network traffic that is not using the correct key. So that the attacking agent does not even know if anything is listening on that port.

Does something similar exist for SSH? So that my ssh server would only reply with login prompt, if authorized clients connects?

Is this perhaps what client-certificate authentication does?

Comment: Are you already using key-based auth (you should!) and have password auth disabled (you should!)?

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz - yes , but that changes nothing on my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The server will completely ignore any network traffic that is not using the correct key. So that the attacking agent does not even know if anything is listening on that port.

SSH is a TCP based protocol. Authentication is done inside the TCP connection, which means that the TCP connection needs to be established first using a TCP handshake. This means that SSH by its own can not have a mechanism where it does not visibly react to network traffic at all before successful authentication.

There are mechanism though like [port knocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking) or a variant [single packet authentication](https://github.com/mrash/fwknop) which add a pre-authentication step and only source IP addresses passing this step will be able to connect to the SSH server.